# Function to build Keras model with arbitrary number of layers

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I want to see what happens to my model when I vary the number of layers it has.

I wrote a function to build, compile and fit a model with a custom number of layers. But it keeps making a (seemingly) identical model each time built with (what looks like) just one layer.

The code

```py
def custom_num_layer_model(num_layers):
    dense_layers = [Dense(16, activation='relu')] * num_layers
    all_layers = dense_layers + [Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')]

    model = Sequential(all_layers)
    
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    history = model.fit(x_train,
                        y_train,
                        epochs=20,
                        batch_size=512,
                        validation_split=0.4)
    return history
```

As I was writing this, I realised it must be the line `dense_layers = [Dense(16, activation='relu')] * num_layers`. This must duplicate the exact layer in the list and thus render the copies useless.

So, how would I write a function to automate this process of building models with a custom number of layers?

Comment: How about `[Dense(16, activation='relu') for _ in range(num_layers)]`?

Comment: You know I'd just had that lightbulb moment a second ago! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Use a list comprehension on the first line of the function.

```py
dense_layers = [Dense(16, activation='relu') for _ in range(num_layers)]
```

You must initialize `num_layers` new objects and so could also do this with a for loop.

Using `list * num_layers` just creates a new list with `num_layers` copies of the original object. Because it's the same object, it was like having a single-layer network.

Using a list comprehension creates `num_layers` distinct new objects and thus it works.